# Quickly Generating A List of of Ordered Lists

Tags: tuples

I'm looking for a quick way to do this.

Define an integer $M$. Function $f[M]$ will output a list of all ordered selections of integers from $1$ to $M$ without repetition. For example:

$f[1] = \{\{1\}\}$

$f[2] =  \{\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\}$

$f[3] =  \{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$

$f[4] =  \{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1,4\},\{2,3\},\{2,4\},\{3,4\}\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,4\},\{1,3,4\},\{2,3,4\},\{1,2,3,4\}\}$

I think this creates a list of length $2^M-1$. So far I've been working with the below:

```
indvals[M_] := (
  l = {};
  raw = Tuples[Table[i, {i, 1, M}], M];
  DeleteDuplicates[
   Table[Sort[DeleteDuplicates[raw[[i]]]], {i, 1, Length[raw]}]]
  )
```

Currently it creates a ton of lists and then cuts out the ones I don't want. Has anyone got a way to make it generate the proper lists in the beginning, or at least a way to reduce the number of cuts that need to be made?

Comment: Hint: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subsets.html   ;}   OR is this possibly homework and you are supposed to figure out how to write code to do this yourself?